Is it possible to add only the new entities and ignore the existing ones?
I am using Entity Framework Core 8 and I have a list of entities that I want to add to the database.
In this list, there could be entities that exist in the database, so if I add all the entities and try to save the changes, I could get an update exception.
Well, one solution could to get from the database the IDs of the entities that are in the list, add to the context the entities that not exist in the database and save the changes. This would work if no other process add and entity that still is in the list.
I could handle the exception, but if when I handle the exception another process add another entity, I would have the same problem.
Another option it would be to use pessimistic concurrency, but I would like to avoid this.
Another option it would be to use raw SQL, and create a T-SQL statement that put each insert inside a try catch and ignore if there is some exception, or at last, a unique exception.
Is there another option? What I would like to do it is try to add all the entities, and if there is some entity that exists in the database, ignore it and add the rest of the entities.
Thanks

This is a question of opinion which is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Also, there are many questions on this subject because it's a very common problem.

@GertArnold In part it can be understand as an opinion question, because I ask about options, but in some way it is a technical question because I ask if Entity Core allows in some way to be configured to work in this way.

I don't see where you ask that. Even so, that has also been asked many times before. Please look at previous questions on this topic.

Cant you use AddOrUpdate?

@Magnus I would like to avoid to update if it exists, I prefer don't touch the record once is added at first time.

How about taking a lock on the rows within a transactionscope?

@Magnus it could be an option, to use pesimistic concurrency, but it could affect to performance, so by the moment I was thinking in another options. I am considerating to to use ADO.NET to use tsql, in where in the insert, I use a where to see if exists the record before try to insert. It is more work, but it will not block the records.

If your going to go with raw SQL I recommend using the merge statement.
CREATE TYPE dbo.MyTableType AS TABLE 
(
    ID INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(50),
    --Add more columns
)

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MergeInsert
    @MyTable dbo.MyTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO TargetTable AS T
    USING @MyTable AS S
    ON (T.ID = S.ID)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT (ID, Name)
        VALUES (S.ID, S.Name);
END

